# Sort column in Dataframe alphabetically after GroupBy

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have used GroupBy to sum the 'Amount' in the dataframe data_2020 .

```
data_2020.groupby(['Category'])['Amount'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

[data_2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVPpa.png)

Now, I want to sort by the column 'Category'. I have tried to use sort_values(by=['Category'], inplace=True) but now I am getting an error message :

TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

How I can sort by column 'Category'?

Comment: `.sort_index()`?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Needs to be `data_2020.groupby(['Category'])['Amount'].sum().sort_index()`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer together with the one below helped me . I used this script: data_2020.groupby(['Category'])['Amount'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).sort_index(ascending=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```
data_2020.groupby(['Category'])['Amount'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

will return a pandas **Series**.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> 
>>> lst = [28793.78, 6380.09, 5895.26, 324.79, 279.76, 239.62]
>>> categories = ['0', 'Amazon', 'Supermarker', 'Taxi', 'Newspapers', 'Boots']
>>> ser = pd.Series(lst, index=categories)
>>> ser.index.name = 'Category'
>>> ser
Category
0              28793.78
Amazon          6380.09
Supermarker     5895.26
Taxi             324.79
Newspapers       279.76
Boots            239.62
dtype: float64
```

[`pandas.Series.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) doesn't accept `by` argument (in contrast to `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values` which does).

---

`sort_index(ascending=True)` should do the trick:

```
>>> ser.sort_index(ascending=True)
Category
0              28793.78
Amazon          6380.09
Boots            239.62
Newspapers       279.76
Supermarker     5895.26
Taxi             324.79
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Gia sou Giorgo, thanks for the detailed explanation. It helped me understand the difference DataFrame and Series. I used the following script which solved my problem: data_2020.groupby(['Category'])['Amount'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).sort_index(ascending=True)